# Is there a better way to write this regex conditional lookup function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, if-statement

I have embarrassingly spent 1.5 days getting the below piece of code to work. It feels clunky using if else statements and poorly written. I wonder if there is a better way to write this that might teach me a better way to handle this type of problem.

What the code is meant to do:

1. Find what the current browser URL is (im looking for marketing parameters on the end i.e. ?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=paid_social)
2. Set a RegEx look up for particular parameters
3. Check the URL to see if it matches any of those parameters
4. Log the result
5. Use a conditional statement to check which combination of parameters exist (don't think it's even using regex at this point)
6. Set the form input value relative to the combination found

Any advice welcomed!

```js
function replaceInput() {

  const leadUrl = window.location.href;
  var utm_sources = RegExp(/linkedin|smartbrief|email_paid|paid_social/g);
  var utms = leadUrl.match(utm_sources);
  console.log(utms);
  
  var leadSourceName = 'Other';

  if (utms.includes('smartbrief')) {
    console.log("We found Smartbrief");
    leadSourceName = 'Smartbrief';
  }

  else if (utms.includes("linkedin" && "email_paid")) {
    console.log("Linkedin Email");
    leadSourceName = 'Linkedin Email';
  }

  else if (utms.includes("linkedin" && "paid_social")) {
    console.log("Linkedin social");
    leadSourceName = 'Linkedin Social';    
  }
  
  else {
    console.log("No UTMs found");
  }

  document.getElementById("LeadSourceTitle").value = leadSourceName;
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: source_sans_proregular,-apple-system,blinkmacsystemfont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}

input {
  height: 51px;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border: 2px solid #c5c5c5;
  caret-color: #44c0ff;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #44c0ff;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="utm-url-test.js"></script>

    </head>
        
    <body>

        <h1>Form test</h1>
        
        <p>Populate the webform input with the utm of the url.</p>

        <form>
            
            <input id="LeadSourceTitle" placeholder="This should be replaced with UTM" onfocus="replaceInput()"></input>
            
        </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for the browser API `URLSearchParams` to fetch the URL param, and regex is just repetitive and skipped in this case.

```
function replaceInput() {

  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search),
      leadSourceName = 'Other';

  if( urlParams.get('utm_source').includes('smartbrief') ){
      leadSourceName = 'Smartbrief';
  } else if( urlParams.get('utm_source').includes('smartbrief') ){
      if( urlParams.get('utm_campaign').includes('email_paid') ){
          leadSourceName = 'Linkedin Email';
      } else if( urlParams.get('utm_campaign').includes('paid_social') ){
          leadSourceName = 'Linkedin Social';
      }
  }

  if( leadSourceName == 'Other' ){
      console.log("No UTMs found");
  } else {
      console.log(leadSourceName);
  }

  document.getElementById("LeadSourceTitle").value = leadSourceName;
}
```

More info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

P.S. You can even try to use a JSON object here if you have many combinations of `utm_source` & `utm_campaign`

Comment: This worked great and using urlParams is far more elegant and accurate that my method.

Thanks!